Prolog DCG in infinite loop without a direct left recursion
TLDR

I have a common pattern that always fall in an infinite loop.

The pattern is
s([H|Rest]) --> non_letters, word(H), non_letters, s(Rest).
s([]) --> [].


I am not 100% sure the cause of an infinite loop.
What are the alternative/preferred method to fix other than converting into a tail recursion form?


Longer version
I always run into an infinite loop when writing DCG in Prolog.
And, it's the same pattern when I use a recursion and I do not spot any left recursion.
For example, say I want to capture a word and ignore every non letters. (basically, whenever I'm writing a lexer like I'm only interested in the meaningful terms rather than space, tabs, ...).
I would write the following Prolog code:
s([H|Rest])    --> non_letters, word(H), non_letters, s(Rest).
s([])          --> [].

non_letters    --> non_letter, non_letters.
non_letters    --> [].

non_letter     --> [C], {\+ code_type(C, alpha)}.

word([L|Rest]) --> letter(L), word(Rest). % <-- NOTE: word also has the same pattern.
word([])       --> [].

letter(C)      --> [C], {code_type(C, alpha)}.

When I run the following query:
?- phrase(s(Out), `Hello World`).

It goes into an infinite loop and never produces a result.
I can fix the infinite loop by fixing word into the tail recursion form, but I can't explain the exact cause of the infinite recursion.
In the simplified grammar, I don't spot any direct left recursion,
but S can result in a left recursion loop if NON_LETTERS and WORD are empty..?
S           --> NON_LETTERS WORD NON_LETTERS S | e
NON_LETTERS --> non_letter NON_LETTERS | e
WORD        --> letter WORD | e

And, fixing word into the tail recursion form would work.
% ... <same as before skip> ...

word(Word)           --> letter(L), word_rest([L], Word).

word_rest(Acc, Word) --> letter(L), word_rest([L|Acc], Word).
word_rest(Acc, Out)  --> [], {reverse(Acc, Out)}.

Helpful links
You can try the above example in the following SWISH.

SWISH link: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/infinite_loop_dcg.pl

Thank you for looking !

Here is a minimal explanation, a failure-slice why your program loops.  First, you have to modify something in the remaining visible part in order to fix non-termination.

:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

s([H|Rest])    --> non_letters, word(H), non_letters, s(Rest), {false}.
s([])          -->  {false}, [].

non_letters    --> {false}, non_letter, non_letters.
non_letters    --> [].

word([L|Rest]) --> {false}, letter(L), word(Rest).
word([])       --> [].

?- phrase(s(Out), "Hello World"), false.
   loops.


The word(H) is slightly misleading - H is normally used in [H|T], but there is no head and tail - it can be [], and therefore loops endlessly without progressing through the list of codes.
Here is a nice method, using empty-list vs non-empty-list distinction, to allow non-letters at the start and end:
non_letter(space) --> " ".
non_letter(tab) --> "\t".
non_letter(newline) --> "\n".
non_letter(newline) --> "\r".

non_letters([]) --> [].
non_letters([H|T]) --> non_letter(H), non_letters(T).

ascii_letter(C) --> [C], { between(0'a, 0'z, C) }.
ascii_letter(C) --> [C], { between(0'A, 0'Z, C) }.

ascii_letters([]) --> [].
ascii_letters([H|T]) --> ascii_letter(H), ascii_letters(T).

% At least 1
word([H|T]) --> ascii_letters([H|T]).

% Ignore non-letters at start
sentence(S) --> non_letters(_), sentence_word(S).

sentence_word([]) --> [].
sentence_word([W|S]) --> word(W), non_letters(NLs), sentence_non(NLs, S).

% Could be end-of-string here
sentence_non([], []) --> [].
% Must have at least 1 non-letter as gaps between the words
sentence_non([_|_], S) --> sentence_word(S).

codes_atoms([], []).
codes_atoms([Cs|CT], [H|T]) :-
    atom_codes(H, Cs),
    codes_atoms(CT, T).

Result in swi-prolog:
?- phrase(sentence(L), `  What is a cat  `), codes_atoms(L, As).
L = [[87, 104, 97, 116], [105, 115], [97], [99, 97, 116]],
As = ['What', is, a, cat] ;
false.


The cause of infinite loop is there was a direct recursion.
For example,
S           --> NON_LETTERS WORD NON_LETTERS S | e
NON_LETTERS --> non_letter NON_LETTERS | e
WORD        --> letter WORD | e

% NOTE
% S --> S when NON_LETTERS and WORD become e


In fact, it was a grammatical error to call WORD has an empty terminal.
The fix is to make word not contain the empty terminal.
word([L|Rest]) --> letter(L), word(Rest).
word([L])      --> letter(L).

In grammar, it becomes
S           --> NON_LETTERS WORD NON_LETTERS S | e
NON_LETTERS --> non_letter NON_LETTERS | e
WORD        --> letter WORD | letter

And, there is no more recursion.
